# Postgres COPY statement - Permission Denied

Tags: postgresql, csv, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.5

I want to copy data from `Postgres` table to `csv` file. I've tried all of the methods written on internet, but get `Permission denied` error. My project is on `Ubuntu` server and I ran following codes to give access my user, but none of them worked.

Destination of my file:

```
/home/betainsurance/insuranceproject/car.csv
```

Scripts for giving accesss:

```
chmod a+rX /home/betainsurance/ /home/betainsurance/insuranceproject /home/betainsurance/insuranceproject/car.csv
```

Postgres query:

```
\c alfaprojectdb;
\COPY m TO '/home/betainsurance/insuranceproject/car.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Error:

```
/home/betainsurance/insuranceproject/car.csv: Permission denied
```

Comment: What does `ls -al /home/betainsurance/insuranceproject/car.csv` show? Are you running the query using `psql` running as you? If not running as you have you tried `chmod a+rwX`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, It returned `-rw-rw-r-- 1`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver `chmod a+rwX` worked, sir, thank you so much !